# Is CryptoJS.AES ironclad by using a random 256 bit string (one time use)?

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs, encryption-symmetric

I'd like to store a secret on my server securely, and permanently. Before storing it, I would run the following code:

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const SECRET = 'secret';
const key = CryptoJS.SHA256(rollHeadOnKeyboard());
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(SECRET, key);

const key2 = CryptoJS.SHA256(rollHeadOnKeyboard());
const doubleEncrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encrypted, key2);

function rollHeadOnKeyboard() {
//random keyboard mashing into 256 bit string
}
```

I encrypt twice so I can keep one key on a server each, meaning two servers would have to be compromised to decrypt the secret. My question is if this is ironclad, i.e. could I upload doubleEncrypted to github and expect it to be secure?

While I'm at it, is choosing a random string myself a horrific security flaw (ie worse than a passphrase with PBKDF2?) Is there some obvious reason I couldn't use this method to encrypt messages between my servers (vs just using TLS)?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the premise here. You have two keys, a secret, and two encrypted values. So what is stored where?

Comment: "rollHeadOnKeyboard" is approximately 40 trillion times less secure than generating a proper, random key. (Not a made-up number; it's the ratio of 2^256 and 96^32, which is **best** case for 32 completely random characters you could easily type on a US keyboard. Actually generating it the way you describe is much, much worse.) So... I don't know if you consider that "iron-clad" or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I encrypt twice so I can keep one key on a server each, meaning two servers would have to be compromised to decrypt the secret.

Generally you'd look into [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) schemes rather than encrypting the data twice. Encrypting the data twice can work of course, but in that case you can also encrypt a fully random "data key" twice and encrypt your messages using that key.

> My question is if this is ironclad, i.e. could I upload doubleEncrypted to github and expect it to be secure?

Systems may be secure or not, algorithms, schemes & protocols are just one way to get there. How will you determine that your server is encrypting for the other server? What exactly happens if one server is compromised? Your code doesn't answer these questions.

> While I'm at it, is choosing a random string myself a horrific security flaw (ie worse than a passphrase with PBKDF2?)

Humans are terrible at generating truly random data. They are worse at remembering it. In this case I don't see the point. Let a password manager generate and store the password and you'd largely avoid both problems.

> Is there some obvious reason I couldn't use this method to encrypt messages between my servers (vs just using TLS)?

Transport protocols do catch a lot of problems. For instance, you could use certificate authentication for both client and server.

Furthermore, CryptoJS only allows for CBC encryption, which doesn't authenticate messages. It is very likely that you'll create a plaintext or padding oracle, allowing an attacker to decrypt the information.

Without message authentication you'd have to worry about an attacker altering and / or replaying your messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you've cleared up most of my misunderstandings. I still seem to misunderstand how a key is generated though. I would have thought a password manager simply chooses some "random" salt and hashes it a bunch of times? Wouldn't I be better off by using myself as a source of randomness, and simply choose a much longer "salt" before generating my key by hashing a bunch of times?

Comment: You can certainly simply create a randomly chosen password directly from a random number generator. The only thing required for that is to choose numbers randomly in a range, which is a solved problem. Maybe you meant a "seed" instead of "salt"? Humans can certainly not match the security of a seed from one or more good entropy sources.

Comment: Yes I meant seed, thank you. Ah I understand what my hang-ups are now, thanks! So to summarize: If I want the encryption to be "iron-clad", I need to flip a coin 256 times to generate the seed of the key I'd then store. If I'm too lazy, I can reduce the bits and replace them with CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(bytesToReplace). Even using all 32 bytes from that function is WAY better than trying to be random myself?

Comment: Yes a well (system) seeded rbg is much better. And hitting all keys with a head roll at the same time is impossible, and many keyboards do not have N-key rollover :P